# Arduino processing serial comunication - losing data?

Tags: serial

I'm trying to send an array back and forth between Processing and an Arduino UNO. But I think data is being lost along the way. I simply iterate over the array in Processing and send the Values separately. A new set of data is indicated by the character `<`. On the Arduino the data gets added to a string and sent back for testing.  When I print out the string in processing, some data changed to `-1`.

The array contains `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`

The Output looks like this:

```
12345678
12345678
1234-1-1-1-1
12345678
12345-1-1-1
```

Is there something I'm missing in terms of implementation, or is this simply a hardware related problem (like slightly different clock speeds)? Is there any way to improve this?

**Arduino Sketch:**

```
int srr[8];

int content; // Data received from the serial port
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

 void loop() {
   String str = "val:";
   int test;
   if (Serial.available()){ // If data is available to read,
     content = Serial.read();
   }

   if (content == 60){
     for(int i=0; i<=7; i++)
   {
       str+=Serial.read();
   }
   Serial.println(str);
   }
}
```

**Processing**

```
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};  //The array to send

String str;
void setup() 
{
  size(200,200); //make our canvas 200 x 200 pixels big
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
  //write
  myPort.write("<");
  for (int i =0; i<=7;i++){
    myPort.write(arr[i]);

  }
  //read
  if ( myPort.available() > 0){  // If data is available,
    str = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
    println(str); //print it out in the console
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's look at your Arduino program a bit at a time (for that is where the problem lies).

```
if (Serial.available()) { // If data is available to read,
    content = Serial.read();
}
```

If there is at least one character available in the buffer then read one character into the variable *content*.

```
if (content == 60) {
```

If the variable content is *60* (better to use '>' so you can see what it is), then ...

```
 for(int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
     str+=Serial.read();
 }
```

... read 8 characters from the serial buffer *whether there are any characters in there or not*.

That last bit is the crunch point.  You have an unknown number of characters in the buffer.  You had at least one, and that one you read into *content*.  You don't then check to see if there are the required 8 more characters available (or wait in each iteration of the loop for each character to actually arrive) before trying to read that character in.

If you take a moment to read the [documentation on Serial Read](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) you will see this:

> **Returns**
>
> the first byte of incoming serial data available *(or -1 if no data is available)* - int

The simplest fix is just to make your loop *blocking* so it waits for a character to arrive before reading it:

```
for(int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
     while (!Serial.available());  // Wait for a character to arrive
     str+=Serial.read();  // Read it
}
```